# React: jsx compiler ignore files and folders list

Tags: compilation, reactjs

Is there a way to provide ignore files or folders list while compiling js files using jsx. I'm aware that it takes config as an option, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The react-tools jsx transformer itself doesn't have an option for excluding files or folders but there are a number of build tools that will let you specify exactly which files it should pass into the jsx transformer. [Grunt-react](https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-react) is a popular choice but there are a [number of tools](https://github.com/facebook/react/wiki/Complementary-Tools#build-tools) you could choose from.